# Usage of expect command within a heredoc

Tags: bash, expect

For the following tiny expect script for which a function was added to the bash profile:

```
chai() {
    expect <<- EOF
    spawn ssh myuser@myserver
    expect ': $'
    send 'mypassword\r'
    EOF
}
```

We get:

```
bash: /etc/profile: line 409: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What is wrong with that script?

Comment: Is the space before the final `EOF` **only** a tab?

Comment: @EtanReisner  You had the correct idea - and the accepted answer basically was the same info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally expect the [heredoc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) terminator (EOF) to be at the *start* of the line e.g.

```
chai() {
    expect <<- EOF
    spawn ssh myuser@myserver
    expect ': $'
    send 'mypassword\r'
EOF
}
```

I see you're using `<<-` and from the linked doc:

> The - option to mark a here document limit string (<<-LimitString)
>   suppresses leading tabs (but not spaces) in the output. This may be
>   useful in making a script more readable.

so you should check the script to see if you have a `TAB` preceding your commands. The EOF is subject to the same rules.

```
cat <<-ENDOFMESSAGE
    This is line 1 of the message.
    This is line 2 of the message.
    This is line 3 of the message.
    This is line 4 of the message.
    This is the last line of the message.
ENDOFMESSAGE
# The output of the script will be flush left.
# Leading tab in each line will not show.
```

Comment: A tab is allowed before the heredoc terminator in with `<<-` as well. It can't tell if it is the heredoc terminator without doing that since it always removes all tabs.

Comment: A link to the bash reference manual section on [here documents](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) is better than that often awful tldp guide.

Comment: @Etan - that document looks a lot nicer and I shall amend. Thx